# Can a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server run without snapd?

Tags: 16.04, snap, memory-usage

I've been running out of memory on some of my small-footprint Ubuntu appliances.  I noticed that `snapd` was running and using lots and lots of RAM. I took a chance and stopped the `snapd` service and things are still functioning, but I'm wondering if my machine is going to reboot properly.

What I want to know is, are there core services in a generic install of Ubuntu 16.04 server that require snaps to function?

Also, what are all the services that I need to disable with `systemctl` to get rid of `snapd`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In versions of Ubuntu **prior** to 18.04, `snapd` is seeded in the default install simply to make installing snaps possible without further work. No part of the base install is a snap (`snap list` shows no snaps installed on a fresh system), and thus `snapd` can be removed with no ill effects:

```
sudo apt purge snapd
```

It will probably leave some dependencies lying around. You may want to remove them as well:

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

**As of Ubuntu 18.04**, fresh installs actually contain snaps. Purging `snapd` like above will remove those snaps. In 18.04 specifically, this wasn't that big of a deal-- the parts of the system shipped as a snap were things like the calculator, that you could still install as a Debian package. However, as of Ubuntu 22.04, more critical things like Firefox are shipped as a snap, and you can't just simply install the Debian package: the Firefox Debian package will just install the snap again. You'll need to find another way to obtain Firefox (e.g. a PPA you trust).

Comment: Using Ubuntu 19.04 with LXDE, removed snapd and system still works after a reboot

Comment: Server 20.04 comes with some snaps installed.  I had to do `snap remove` on `lxd`, `core18` and `snapd`.  Possibly in that order, due to dependencies.

Comment: @mwfearnley I believe purging snapd would have done that for you, did you try it?

Comment: Alas, I did not.  If I have another opportunity, I will try it.  Thanks.

Comment: Does somebody know if core is somewhat relevant? I've got them too.

Comment: Purge should remove that as well, @Apollo.

Comment: Just be careful with the autoremove. It could potentially remove things that you need. In my case startx couldn't start anymore because the package xserver-xorg-legacy had been removed

Answer (score 8):

Bug #1642068 was logged against this issue and has recently been fixed: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1642068

Comment: That only happens if you're constantly installing and removing snaps (the bug reported installed/removed a snap every 3 seconds)

Comment: Some of the work involved here was to fix the generic case of snapd's memory utilization, so I believe the fix was wider than the original bug report issue.

Comment: Either way, it seemed like it was using a fairly large chunk of the available ram for something that wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Indeed. Daemons should be relatively compact and lightweight for sure.