# Can a fresh installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server run without snapd?

Tags: server, uninstall, snap

I know, that there ist this Question: [Can a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server run without snapd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878431/can-a-vanilla-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-run-without-snapd)

But the situation is different on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server.
If I run `snap list` on fresh installed VM I get:

```
Name    Version   Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
core18  20200311  1705   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
lxd     4.0.1     14804  latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snapd   2.44.3    7264   latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
```

Is it save to deactivate them and to remove snap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to remove snapd on Ubuntu Server 20.04.

However, you will not be able to use LXD containers.

- LXD in Ubuntu 20.04 is available by snap ONLY. The deb package is transitional, and merely installs the snap.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. However I could just install lxd via apt? (Maybe interessting for others)

Comment: @KaeTuuN edited the answer to address your question.