# Does removing snap from Ubuntu 20.04 server pose any problem?

Tags: apt, server, 20.04, snap

I am creating a new VM instance on the google cloud platform with `ubuntu-os-cloud/ubuntu-2004-lts` as my boot disk image. I observed that some snap packages are being installed by default including the `google-cloud-sdk`. Now I use `apt` for all the package management on the servers and don't necessarily have a problem with snap being present. I have found quite some articles on removing `snapd` from Ubuntu, but what I wanted to enquire is whether keeping the `snap` as it is and keep working with apt for my package management will pose any issues.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a vanilla Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server run without snapd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/878431/can-a-vanilla-ubuntu-16-04-lts-server-run-without-snapd)

Comment: Not exactly, I know that the server can run without snapd. What I want to know is if I don't remove snap and keep using apt, will I encounter any problems in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes if you are using snap installed applications removing snap will also remove them.

Snap I gather has become a secondary install method within Ubuntu which is why its been installed by default.

Snap is a lot more flexible than apt which is why its gained in popularity though its not going to replace apt without some major enhancements.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is designed to use snap packages as the delivery platform for software.
Apparently, on the Google Cloud Platform, Ubuntu has been configured to automatically install the `google-cloud-sdk` for you, and by effect to keep it up to date. It makes sense to use these facilities since they have been designed to help you and you get support for them.

If you really want to remove `snapd` and the snap packages, you can obviously do so as well. However, you would need to be able to install and maintain manually the `google-cloud-sdk` and other default packages.

Comment: I don't want to delete the snapd service or the related packages, just wanted to know if using both snap and apt poses any issues?

Comment: No, they do not pose any issues. If you have installed the same snap and apt package, note that it is up to you to know which executable you are running each time.

Comment: If your asking could there be conflicts then the answer his no they install into different locations /snap rather than /usr.    So unless you have a very strange path its fine..